# Proper way to manually set the layout of a window in Qt

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmainwindow, qlayout, qgridlayout

I need a QMainWindow layout to change depending on the number of cores.
Therefore I set it manually (not using the Design mode).

My question is:
After this layout was created, how can I refer to the widgets it contains?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //...
    buildLayout();
    //...

    // Now I'd like to use something like this:
    // ui->threadingTable->...
    // However, it's not the member of ui
}

void MainWindow::buildLayout()
{
    QWidget *window = new QWidget(this);

    QTableView *threadingTable = new QTableView(window);
    //...

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(window);
    layout->addWidget(threadingTable, 0, 0);
    //...

    window->setLayout(layout);
    this->setCentralWidget(window);
}
```

I can get the QLayoutItem out of `this->centralWidget()`.
Or I can make all widgets in layout members of MainWindow class and access them directly.

However, I feel that neither of these is the right way.

Is there a way to pass the widgets to ui?
So that I could access them by calling
`ui->threadingTable`

Comment: In my opinion there's nothing wrong in making the widgets also members of the "main" class. Of course you don't usually need to access all of them and signals might be connected before adding them to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are fine. It is possible to get pointer to `threadingTable` from the main class member or directly from the objects hierarchy:

```
qDebug() << qobject_cast<QGridLayout *>(this->centralWidget()->layout())->itemAtPosition(0, 0)->widget();
qDebug() << this->centralWidget()->layout()->itemAt(0)->widget();
```

Of course, `null` verification may be required. You can also check this question [QGridLayout: Getting the list of QWidget added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160526/qgridlayout-getting-the-list-of-qwidget-added).

The class `Ui::MainWindow` is automatically generated from the `.ui` xml form that can be generated in the Design mode: ["Using a Designer UI File in Your Application"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html)

Since the layout is constructed manually the `.ui` file and the `ui` instance is not needed at all. You can remove them from your project.

On the other hand, it is possible to use custom widgets even in the Design mode in `.ui` forms.
So, if you need some tricky object you can build the entire form in handy Design mode and then, for example, the standard `QTableView` may be promoted to your `CustomTableView` that is inherited from `QTableView`. That custom class may implement some special behavior.